# Wrap div based on content inside it

Tags: javascript, html, css

div's width is 100% so there's lot of extra space left at right. I want div to wrap the text inside it i.e. no extra space should be left in the block. How to achieve it?

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black;">
  Hello there!
</div>
```

Comment: can you describe in detail what you need?

Comment: @WilliamWang Did you got it now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `display: inline-block`:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black;display: inline-block">
  Hello there!
</div>
```

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid black;display: inline-block;border: solid">
  Hello there!
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain how it worked?

Comment: `div` by default is `block` i.e it will take fullwidth. `inline-block` takes the width of the content as in `button, a, span etc`. You can read more abt it here https://dev.to/shimphillip/inline-vs-inline-block-vs-block-280h

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: inline-flex`

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black; display: inline-flex">
  Hello there!
</div>
```

Also if you are not familiar with flex and what it is used for, I recommend having a look at this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Good reference to understand the power of using flexbox

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want that complete text of `div` should remain inside your div instead of giving `scroll` So you can use :

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```